# Realm error at getDefaultInstance when plugin updated to 2.2.1

Tags: android, realm

I updated my realm plugin to 2.2.1 and I got this error when calling:
**realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();**

*Error:*

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "io.realm.internal.ColumnInfo io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.validateTable(java.lang.Class, io.realm.internal.SharedRealm, boolean)"
```

*Init time in the application file:*

```
public void initRealm(){

    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

}
```

*Full stacktrace:*

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "io.realm.internal.ColumnInfo io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.validateTable(java.lang.Class, io.realm.internal.SharedRealm, boolean)"
at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:342)
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:299)
at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:264)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:143)
at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:209)
at inc.primssware.dekon.classes.MyProductsProvider.<init>(MyProductsProvider.java:32)
at inc.primssware.dekon.activities.AccountActivity.onCreate(AccountActivity.java:117)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6881)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: please post full code of your Application class

Comment: You seem to have a dependency on an older version of Realm. Please post build.gradle dependencies, `apply plugin` order, and `gradle dependencies` command line command output

Comment: Also try clean+rebuild

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();

    // Clear the realm from last time
   // Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);

    // Create a new empty instance of Realm
    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

https://github.com/gohilmehul/Realm/blob/master/RealMDemo/app/src/main/java/com/mg/realmdemo/MyApplication.java